# How to generate MD5 encrypted password in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, scripting, passwords

I need to generate MD5 password from provided informations. Following is my MySQL database table;

```
sN | firstN | lastN   | countryN | dob        | emailID            | joinD      | uID     | passwd   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Roger  | Federer | German   | 1981-08-08 | rfederer@gmail.com | 2009-12-23 |40345689 | ???????? |
   |        |         |          |            |                    |            |         |          |
```

Generated password should be like this:

```
<first two characters from lastN> + <dob month> + <dob day> + <last two digit from uID> + "=$"
```

In this case;

```
Password : "Fe080889=$"
Encrypted Password : "d76c30608603f7bf0a07abb03c6a631f"
```

Please somebody help me with this. How do I do it using bash script or is there any way to do it itself in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL (depending on your version). It has built-in encryption/checksum functions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5

Just use a combination of substring and date-parsing functions to concatenate the pieces of the fields you need, and pass the string through `MD5()`.

Roughly:

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(LEFT(lastN, 2), MONTH(dob), DAY(dob), RIGHT(CAST(uID, CHAR), 2), '=$'))
FROM Table
```